# Inner Product on $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ true/false

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form, positive-definite

The question was to classify each statement as true or false with justification:

Define $\langle f, g\rangle$ = $\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) \,dx $. Then, $\langle , \rangle$ is an inner product on $P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

My solution below concluded that it was true, however my classmate said the statement was false, and although I didn't completely understand their proof, I am beginning to doubt mine. Can anyone clarify if my justification is legitimate?

Rewrite $\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) \,dx $ as $$\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x)\,dx + \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x) \,dx $$ 
For $\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x)\,dx$, integrate by parts to get $f(x)g(x) - \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)\,dx$. Substitute this result into the rewritten form of $\langle f, g \rangle$, we get $$<f,g>=f(x)g(x) - \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x)\,dx + \int_0^1 f(x)g'(x) \,dx =f(x)g(x)$$
Then, (proving the three properties of inner products) $\langle f,f\rangle =[f(x)]^2\ge0$, also $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ iff $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Thus, it is positive definite.
Next, $\langle f,g\rangle=f(x)g(x)=g(x)f(x)=\langle g,f\rangle$ so $\langle f,g\rangle$ is symmetric.
Finally, $$\langle sf+tg,h \rangle=(sf(x)+tg(x))h(x)=s(f(x)h(x))+t(g(x)h(x))=s\langle f,h\rangle+t\langle g,h\rangle $$ So $\langle f,g \rangle$ is bilinear, and is thus an inner product on $P_3R$.

Likely made a silly mistake somewhere or my thinking is wrong, any tips would be helpful!

Comment: Well, actually, $$\int_0^12f'(x)f(x)\,dx=(f(1))^2-(f(0))^2$$ so $\langle f,\,f\rangle$ is not necesairly $\ge 0$. In fact, if $f(x)=1-x$, $$\langle f,\,f\rangle=\int_0^12x-2\,dx=-1$$

Comment: Notice that by your calculations $\langle f, g \rangle = f(x)g(x)$. But $x$ is just the dummy variable used for integrating, so this makes no sense. Furthermore, if $f$ and $g$ are both constant, then clearly $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Note that $f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = (f(x)g(x))'$ so your inner product is really just $f(1)g(1)-f(0)g(0)$. You made a (not so) minor error. When doing *definite* integrals, $\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)\,dx = f(x)g(x)|_a^b -\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx.$ If you are not sure about this, consider the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the inner product is not quite correct; you should have

\begin{align*}
\langle f, g \rangle &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) g(x) \, dx \\
&= f(x) g(x) \big|_0^1 \\
&= f(1) g(1) - f(0) g(0)
\end{align*}

This does not define an inner product, although it is bilinear. For example, any function $f$ that vanishes at both $0$ and $1$ will have zero "norm" - to be explicit, if $f(x) = x(x - 1)$ then $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$.